# Conditional formatting values with specific character/digit count

Tags: excel

I'm using this formula `=len(a1)<3` to highlight cell values which have less then 3 characters/digits. How can i do the same task to highlight cells with character count between 3 and 5? Instead of just smaller or bigger than function, i want to use between two numbers? thanks.

Comment: (untested) `=and(3<(a1),(a1)<5)`?

Comment: thanks, I tried it, but it didn't do any highlighting.

Comment: Try `=AND(3<A1,A1<5)` (note that only cells with a value of 4 will highlight with that condition)

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result.

Comment: ok, I tried this =AND(LEN(T1)>3,LEN(T1)<5) and it works. thanks. I just needed to use len in the formula. if you post it as answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the values the formula should be:

```
=AND(3<A1,A1<5)
```

For the character count, it should be

```
=AND(3<LEN(A1),LEN(A1)<5)
```